# What is it that clobbers my letters together in Gedit?

Tags: gedit

Sometimes, after I’ve been editing a text file in Gedit, the letters clobber together like this:

[image: Screenshot showing overlapping letters on the final line]

Why is this? How can I stop it from happening?

Comment: Have you (perhaps accidentally) been using a non-ASCII character that would switch to a right-to-left display? Does the problem persist if you page up and down? What if you close and reopen the file?

Comment: no, yes, and yes

Comment: Given “yes” to the third question: post a problematic file somewhere (e.g. on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)).

Comment: @Gilles usually when this happens i just delete the file and start over. but who should i notify when this pops up again?

Comment: Send relevant data to [the bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=127731) [cited by lesmana](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10187/what-is-it-that-clobbers-my-letters-together-in-gedit/10193#10193), if you have new information that isn't covered already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be an effect of this bug: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=127731

The bug is triggered when you have a very long line (something over 500k chars). You can stop it from happening by inserting some line breaks. If you really need the long line without line breaks then you will have to use another editor until the bug is fixed.

Comment: yes, that makes sense to me -- for the record, i only encounter the error sometimes. not all the time.